# Highcharts Column Series Point Object Click Function

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Recently I posted a question on Highcharts column charts drilldown. I have found that in click event of point object you can find out which column was clicked. I have implemented the same in my code but I am not getting alert in my code. Please find below my code. First is my chart options variable -

```
var columnoptions = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Column Chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Exposure'
                    }
                },              
                plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            alert ('here');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
                series: []
            };
```

I am filling the series dynamically with below statements in a loop -

```
columnoptions.xAxis.categories.push(categoryArray[index]);

             seriesOptions.data.push(valueArray[index]);
```

Finally I display my chart like this -

```
         chart = new Highcharts.Chart(columnoptions);
```

But I am not getting any alert on column click. I get error javascript error messages in IE. I am using IE8. Kindly help  me with this. Highcharts official example with static data works fine and I have seen that. My chart displays correctly without any issues. But I need to know which column was clicked to implement drilldown functionality. Please help.

---Edit
Here is the full function I am using to draw the charts-

```
function displayColumnChart(){

         columnoptions.series = [];
         columnoptions.xAxis.categories = [];          



         var seriesOptions = {
                        name: 'Column Chart',
                        data: [],                       

                    };  

         /* category array contains x axis category values
            value array contains y axis numeric values */

         for(index = 0; index < categoryArray.length; index++){

             columnoptions.xAxis.categories.push(categoryArray[index]);

             seriesOptions.data.push(valueArray[index]);        

         }      

         columnoptions.series.push(seriesOptions);     

         chart = new Highcharts.Chart(columnoptions);
       }
```

I am reading my data from an XML doc and then creating value and category array. Chart comes fine but not getting alert on point click. Please help. Thanks. :) Sorry for delay in posting the code.

Comment: What `seriesOptions` is ? Can you show me all your code and provide a demo if possible ?

Comment: "I get error javascript error messages in IE" -- and these errors are?

Comment: seriesOptions is the series: [] part of columnoptions. Its basically a map with key value pairs. Keys are title and data. I am pushing values to be plotted into the data part of the seriesoptions and then this I am pushing into columnoptions' 'series' part. I will provide the code tomorrow if you want as it is in office. :)

Comment: the errors were from Highcharts.js file which we include in the code. I will provide the exact error tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: your `plotoptions` - click function - works fine [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6MX/) , try passing your data to the chart object and and see if this will help

Comment: I have added my code. Please see Edit.

Comment: @MinaGabriel My code is working in Chrome but not in IE8. :(.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann Did you see my edit? I have givn the function I am using to build the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only added the latest version of the highcharts and point click is working for me. Thanks.